# How to make callback change plot in every iteration?

Tags: matlab, callback, iteration

I have got 4 callbacks in my GUI and 12 plots which I put images into. Each button loads a different image. How can I make my callbacks change the plot in each iteration?

```
function A_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
axes(handles.dna1)
matlabImage = imread('a.png');
image(matlabImage)
axis off
axis image
```

This is my code for the first callback. The others are the same (only image is different). The thing is that I have 12 plots (from dna1 to dna12). After chosing a callback, i want the next choice should be about the next plot (dna2, dna3, etc.). How can I do that?

[image]

When I click any of the callback the image of the letter should be loaded to the first plot. Next click on any other callback should refer to the next plot which is next the first one.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand your question. By choosing a `callback` you mean plotting an image in an `axes`. Here, you have 4 `callbacks` and 12 `axes`. How do you want to implement the assignment of 4 `callback` into 12 `axis` in your loop (e.g. with steps of 3). Can you post an image of your current GUI and share the link here? Also, please share the loop that you've written so far for calling your `callbacks`?

Comment: @hmofrad I put the gui in the question. However I don't have any loop becouse i have no idea how to refer to specific plot there. Firstly, I tried to put them in an array but it seems matlab doesn't work like java and i still can't transfer it to callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to pass the *next axis id* to the next `callback` function you are going to use. So, try to add the following steps to your code:

1. In `DNA_OpeningFcn` add 2 new elements `axesid` and `axesnum` to the `handles` struct in order to identify the next `axes` to pick:

   ```
   handles.output = hObject;
   handles.axesid = 0;
   handles.axesnum = 12;
   % Update handles structure
   guidata(hObject, handles);
   ```
2. Then, change your `callbacks` implementation as follows as you are trying to set the next axis:

   ```
   handles.axesid = mod(handles.axesid, handles.axesnum) + 1;
   ax = ['dna',int2str(handles.axesid)];
   axes(handles.(ax))
   matlabImage = imread('coins.png'); % Change the input image
   image(matlabImage)
   axis off
   axis image
   guidata(hObject, handles);
   ```

Make sure that you named your axes as `dna1` to `dna12`.

Comment: I think this is not what I want. I updated the question with code example, can you look at this?

Comment: My bad! I didn't completely understand the question! Please try to give more details about your problem as I stated in my above comment for your question.

Comment: Now, your question seems more clear!  I totally changed the answer. Hope this time works for you!

Comment: yes, it is exactly what I wanted but unfortunately it starts from the second plot

Comment: You need to set the `handles.axesid = 0;` and you'll be fine!

Comment: yeah, I just got the idea myself :D one more question, do you know how to stop this iteration after 12 plot?

Comment: Nevermind previous question, I just did it. Thanks for all help! :)

Comment: That's great!  In the answer I used `mod` to calculate the next `axis` and it will start from the beginning after reaching `dna12 axes`! I think, this would be something that you would like to have!